# Call A Command Line Java Program From Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework

I am creating a hybrid smartphone app for which the REST API I am writing in Play Framework(Java). The main algorithm for the app is a stand alone Java command line app which I want to call from the REST API function when need be. Is this possible from Play Framework or shall I try and create the algorithm inside a play framework method.

Request Flow:

```
[PhoneGap Compiled App]->[REST API (Play Framework)]->[Java App (Algorithm)]
```

Response Flow:

```
[PhoneGap Compiled App]<-[REST API (Play Framework)]<-[Java App (Algorithm)]
```

I don't have much code to publish yet, I hope there is enough information to answer my question: **Can I run the Java App from the Play Framework?**

Comment: This seems like a very fragile approach.  Why can't you use the stand-alone app as a library?

Comment: I'm new to Java, I'm a PHP guy... would you help link me to someplace that shows me how to do that?